# Loading the full site and then displaying, allowing video content to fully download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been having a issue with my html5 videos not loading fully and therefore freezing/stuttering at times, I need to give them time to load and want to put together something that will stop the page from displaying until the page and content is fully loaded therefore allowing my videos enough time to download properly.

What is the best/simplest way to achieve this?

Someone suggested not starting automatic playback before the readyState reaches HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA (4) but not sure how to implement this.

I basically want to put a div around the site and not load that div until the site is fully ready to be seen...

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Let's start out by showing the code you're using for your video. That 'someone' made a good point.

Comment: Hiding the whole site while waiting for a video to download is not a pleasant user experience imo. You might want to show a loader (overlaying the video) and removing it when the event [canplay or canplaythrough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) is fired.

Comment: What they said was a good point but I'm not sure how to execute it in the code. I have a loading gif that I want to display until it is fully loaded and then display the site to avoid any freezing for the user as the videos have autoplay applied to them. Please excuse my lack of knowledge on the matter but I have a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SRJ5m/1/ and basically I want to play a video once it has had time to fully load if autoplay is set to it. Displaying only the load overlay on top until load is complete. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this library to go with: http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/.

The site has samples and API documentation to start with.